# motd with utf-8 encoding in Ubuntu Server 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, encoding, utf-8

I've just changed default motd in Ubuntu (I edited /etc/update-motd.d/* files) and added some string in polish:

```
echo "Aby uzyskać dodatkowe informacje i przykładowe skrypty wpisz:"
```

but autogenerated /etc/motd is without accent characters:

```
Aby uzyska dodatkowe informacje i przykadowe skrypty wpisz:
```

So "ć" and "ł" is missing. So how to enable utf-8 encoding in motd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LANG environment variable to enable UTF-8 encoding. Just edit your script file (under `/etc/update-motd.d/*`) by adding the line:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it is not working.

Comment: I've just tried it again and now it is working. When I edited my files with motd there was no accecnt characters at all (it is strange, because I was writing motd with them several times). I added them and now it works. Thanks for your answer!